# Create a batch to automate HTTPS GET requests

Tags: cookies, https, automation, get

how can i create a batch that can send HTTPS requests ?
byfar i used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/dl/Fiddler2Setup.exe)  Request Builder so i can send requests like:

```
GET https://website.com/index.aspx?typeoflink=**[HERE-VARIABLE-FROM-FILE]**&min=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: https://website.com/index.aspx?chknumbertypeoflink&min=1
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Host: website.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: cookieverrylongstringD%FG^&N*MJ( CVV%^B&N*&*(NHN*B*&BH*&H
```

But i have to mannualy change the variable NOT GOOD...
So the script would send many Requests and just changing the **[HERE-VARIABLE-FROM-FILE]** variable
The variables are textnames in a file (one variable per line)
if this could be done in a batch file or vbs or jscript or anything!

Thanks in advance!
adam

Comment: You should tell what operation system you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to download a version of `curl` for Windows, and then write a batch file that invokes curl.

```
set TYPEOFLINK=foo
curl https://website.com/index.aspx?typeoflink=%TYPEOFLINK%&min=1 > savedfile
```

Comment: and it could send cookies also ?

Comment: i need to send the whole thing with User-Agent Cookie and etc

Comment: Mike i used your script and it works... but how can i make it to send the User-Agent and Cookie ?

Comment: "curl --help" will show options for these things: `--cookie <name=string/file>` and `--user-agent <string>`.

Comment: thanks alot the only problem left is that curl doesnt process the full link as is it puts spaces between & characters , i tryed with " "

Comment: Put a "^" immediately before each "&".

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume Windows because you mention Fiddler.
You can use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which runs under cygwin.
curl is a command line tool which will allows you to initiates GET requests.